# Can anyone identify this plant found in a rooftop garden?

Tags: identification, flowers

I found this plant in a rooftop garden in Pittsburgh, PA. Any ideas as to what it is?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't see the leaves, but if the picture was taken at the end of summer/autumn, it's probably [Michaelmas Daisy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aster_amellus).

Comment: aka Asters in North America. The key is the purple petals that resemble a daisy, around a yellow centre. And that they bloom in the fall.

Answer (score 4):

Aster Azureus, A native aster. This would make a good roof-top plant because it tolerates very dry soil in full sun.
http://www.prairienursery.com/store/native-plants/sky-blue-aster-aster-azureus